# Making an entire model read-only with Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I see that Mongoid supports read-only attributes.  Is there a way to mark an entire document, or an entire collection / model class as read-only?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access the `fields` class attribute and splat the hash's keys against `attr_readonly`. For example:

```
class Model
  include Mongoid::Document

  attr_readonly *fields.keys
end
```

Note that, `fields.keys` will include `_id` and `_type`.