# Make mongoid session read only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have different sessions in my `mongoid.yml`, where one session provides data from a static mongo database. I was wondering if it is possible, to "load" a session in read only mode, so that no changes with `save`, `create`, `destroy` or `destroy_all` can be made. My `mongoid.yml` looks like this:

```
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: my_app_production
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        read: primary
    static_content:
      database: static_content_db
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        read: primary
  options:
    use_utc: true
```

I have special models for the `static_content` session, they look like this:

```
  class StaticMappings
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic
    store_in collection: "static_mappings", session: "static_content"
  end
```

I want to prevent myself form accidentially calling things like `StaticMappings.destroy_all` or a `StaticMappings.create(...)`. Is this possible?

I found this [Making an entire model read-only with Mongoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573914/making-an-entire-model-read-only-with-mongoid), but this won't prevent someone from calling `create` or `destroy` on a model instance.

Answer (score 3):

That's an old question, but I met the same problem recently, so decided to share. Although, I want to notice, that this is not a per-sesson solution, but a per-model one.

As I figured out, there are two ways to make it possible:

## 1. Redefine `readonly?`

If you look through the Mongoid code, you'll see that all functions that save, delete or update, call `readonly?` to check if the model is read-only. Not really documented and has a drawback -- create and create! are allowed on this model (destroys, updates, saves won't run though).

```
private

def readonly?
  true
end
```

## 2. A custom callback

In addition to the previous method you can add callback(s) to ensure that even creates won't pass through:

```
before_create :readonly_secret

private

def readonly?
  true
end

def readonly_secret
  raise Mongoid::Errors::ReadonlyDocument, self.class if readonly?
end
```

Essentialy, you can get rid of `readonly?` method alltogether, and add other callbacks such as `before_save`, `before_destroy`, `before_update`, `before_create`

### Manipulate "readonliness"

if you feel a need to manipulate read-only state from a runtime code, you can define an attribute for your model's class:

```
before_create :readonly_secret

class << self
  attr_accessor :readonly
end

private

def readonly?
  self.class.readonly.nil? ? true : self.class.readonly
end

def readonly_secret
  raise Mongoid::Errors::ReadonlyDocument, self.class if readonly?
  true
end
```